# How do I import data from mysql local to Hive(University) without using sqoop?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have MySql installed in the local system and it has [employee](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html) database, I want to transfer data from local MySQL to Hive(University) without using Sqoop(I don't have permission to install Sqoop), how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import CSV from MySQL and Load to Hive using load local inpath.